# how to keep entries at least 1/2'' away from the page number column

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I am working on my dissertation and I am facing a problem in the LOF only for the appendix figures. They go too close to the number column.
How to keep entries at least 1/2'' away from the page number column?

[image]

All the figures outside the appendix section are working fine

```
\chapter*{\vspace*{0.65in}{Appendix A: \ Experiment Instruments and Draw Sheets}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{A.\arabic{figure}}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. It would also be useful if you showed how entries in the LOF are formatted for figures in the non-appendix part of the document.

Comment: Assuming the entry is being formatted by `\@dottedtocline`, the right margin is given by `\@tocrmarg` but that includes the page number `\@pnumwidth` so `\renewcommand{@tocrmarg}{\the\dimexpr \@pnumwidth+0.5in}`.  You may need `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`.

Comment: OTOH, it appears you are using a custom `\l@figure`.

Comment: I figured that the problem is everywhere not only on the appendices, so how can I adjust it the spacing between the entries and the numbering in LOF. I am using a custom document class https://github.com/soooleh/dissertationLaTeX @Mico